# Remove duplicate Tuples from an ArrayList- Java

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, redundancy

I want to have an unique List of tuples without duplicates.

```
List <Tuple>  newNonZeros = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in newNonZeroes is the result: `[(0,2)(1,2)(1,2)(1,1)(2,2)(2,2)(2,1)]`

Here's what I tried:

```
List <Tuple> newList = new ArrayList<>();
newList.add(newNonZeros.get(0));

for(int i=1; i < newNonZeros.size();i++){
    if(newNonZeros.get(i-1)!= newNonZeros.get(i)){
        newList.add(newNonZeros.get(i));
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. Can someone help me...it's a very simple problem

I also tried the following method:

```
...newNonZeros.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: List<Tuple> newNonZeros = new ArrayList<>();*

Comment: Removing duplicated elements makes me think about set

Comment: `!=` checks for reference equality not data equality.  You need to use `equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Tuple` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Tuple tuple = (Tuple) o;
    return first == tuple.first &&
            second == tuple.second;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(first, second);
}
```

Then you can use:

```
List<Tuple> newList = newNonZeros.stream()
                               .distinct()
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or with a for-each loop:

```
List<Tuple> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Tuple tuple : newNonZeros) {
    if(!newList.contains(tuple)) {
        newList.add(tuple);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate =)